# replaceState with empty string: Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've got this url:

```
website.com/con?blog=true
```

What I do in javascript is:

```
if (getURLparams(blog)) {
   RandomFunction();
   // change the url
   window.history.replaceState({}, '?blog=true', "blog=false");
}
```

However, I do not want to use `blog=false`, in fact I want empty string there. I tried `""`/`''` but they didn't work.
Any idea or alternative? Thanks

Comment: The third parameter in `replaceState` is optional so you can not set it at all

Comment: Tried. Didn't work. I want `?blog=true` gone completely

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set it to `location.pathname`:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '', location.pathname);
```

This will remove the URL params.

Comment: It did the trick, thanks! `replaceState` is, in my opinion, preferable if you want to update URL only, without reloading your page. You can take advantage not to worry about history and get back to initial state.

Comment: If appears to work. But when I do this, and then reloads the page, the old url is loaded.

Comment: @johnohod which browser? Are you sure it's not the page itself that does set these params?

Comment: Safari and Firefox at least. Yes I’m sure. It’s working fine when I add the parameters and reloads, not when I remove and reload.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a relative path:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '', './');
```

Comment: This doesn't just replace the query string, but also removes whatever is after the last /

Answer (score -3):

You can try.. Emptying the last parameter of function replaceState.
Like this.

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '?blog=true', "");
```

or

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '?blog=true');
```

Comment: Using empty string or undefined does not change the url at all, which is clearly not what was required.