# prevent history.replaceState appending to the url

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I am using `window.history.replaceState` and having some issues in that it keeps appending to the url.

It has been marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805986/replacestate-with-empty-string-javascript)which I think is a mistake as when I use that code the same issue is occurring and it keeps appending the index to the url as described below.

Please see my code below:

```
let index = 1;

function incrementIndexAndUpdateUrl() {
   index++;
   window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', `${window.location.href }/${index}`);
}
```

The issue I am having is that the url keeps appending the number so it is doing something like the following:

https://slackoverflowz.com/questions/ask/2/3/4

Does anyone know how the code should look to update the url like as follows:

- https://slackoverflowz.com/questions/ask/2
- https://slackoverflowz.com/questions/ask/3
- https://slackoverflowz.com/questions/ask/4

**It is also worth noting the url is dynamic so I can't hardcode the path. I just want to update the index at the end of the url.**

Comment: Have you tried removing the last numbers and then adding index?

Comment: @LucaKiebel how do you mean?

Comment: `const index` and `index++`? Also `window.location.href` will contain the numbers you've just appended

Comment: You should do it from `window.location.origin` and start appending the `pathname`

Comment: @George sorry, I just wrote the code here, it is actually in a. react component, there is no issue with `const`. You are correct though, that is the issue

Comment: @George have you any idea how to resolve this? I know how I could hack it together, but think there must be a nicer way

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed your last `/` will actually be part of the pathname... You'd need to store the orignal pathname before calling replaceState the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are appending an `/something`, you are actually changing the pathname. 
So the easy way, is to store the original one before you do change it:

```js
let index = 1;
const path = location.pathname;

btn.onclick = incrementIndexAndUpdateUrl;

function incrementIndexAndUpdateUrl() {
   index++;
   window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', `${path}/${index}`);
   console.log(location.href);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">increment</button>
```

[And as a fiddle for Chrome.](https://jsfiddle.net/a46k8wxm/)

Answer (score 0):

You should do it from window.location.origin and start appending the pathname, so probably your answer would be

```
let index = 1;

function incrementIndexAndUpdateUrl() {
   index++;
  window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', `${window.location.origin}/question/ask/${index}`);
}
```

Comment: sorry @mohit the url is dynamic